# C++, Poco Socketstream to Websocket for JSON packet transfer

Tags: c++, json, websocket, poco-libraries

I'm working on a project that is relying fairly heavily on packet latency. The architect for the overall system wants to use the Poco::Net::Websocket protocol as the transport layer between the different nodes. We have been running the application with ZMQ till this point, but there's too much overhead and we are not seeing the speeds we need. So I'm tasked with converting the ZMQ portion of the system over to WebSockets.

I've never used WebSockets before and I'm having issues understanding what's going on. I know WebSockets were originally designed as a way to speed up communication between the web browser and the page server decreasing latency through the use of full-duplex bi-directional communication.

There are a lot of tutorials for javascript, nodejs, and even python, but it's more limited when you're talking about C++, which is what I'm working with. The examples that I have found are geared more towards browser requests, which I'm not surprised by. Rather than general TCP packet transfer, which is what our use case would be.

Here are my thoughts and questions.

Seeing how I couldn't really understand what was happening, I decided to start with a Poco::Net::SocketStream configuration first. I chose to do it this way, based on the thought that Websockets are nothing more than a TCP socket inserted into a higher-level protocol framework. I figured transitioning would be easier than trying from scratch. So I spun up a server and client application using standard Poco socket libraries.

I used the example [here](https://github.com/andweeb/poco-test) as a base. I just ended up moving everything to a single file. I also spun up a Poco::Net::TCPServer as well, a sample found [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Net/samples/tcpserver/src/tcpserver.cpp).

I modified both to manage the fact that I'm sending JSON packets between the client and server. I took snippets of our original code to format the JSON packets and encode them with CBOR. I ended up keeping the zmq::message_t format that I was originally using, as I ran into issues receiving the packets on the other end. So as it wasn't the major issue I just skipped that part for now. So I'm aware the ZMQ portions of the code below aren't necessary, a small problem for another time.

Here is the Client code for reference.

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h"
#include "Poco/Net/WebSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include "Poco/Net/WebSocket.h"
#include <jsoncons/json.hpp>
#include <jsoncons/json.hpp>
#include <jsoncons_ext/cbor/cbor.hpp>
#include <jsoncons_ext/jsonpath/json_query.hpp>
#include <jsoncons_ext/jsonpath/jsonpath.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <zmq.hpp>

using namespace jsoncons;
using Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession;
using Poco::Net::HTTPMessage;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequest;
using Poco::Net::HTTPResponse;
using Poco::Net::WebSocket;

class ClientHandler
{
private:
    std::string host;
    int port;

    // IP endpoint/socket address (consists of host addr and port #)
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress socketAddr;

    // Interface to a TCP stream socket
    // Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket;
    Poco::Net::Socket socket;

    // Stream for reading from / writing to a socket (accepts a socket)
    Poco::Net::SocketStream stream;

public:
    ClientHandler(std::string h, int p) : host(h), port(p), socketAddr(h, p), socket(), stream(socket)
    {
        std::cout << "Host: " << host << "\tPort: " << port << std::endl;
    }

    // Connect to the initialized socket address' hostname and port
    bool connected()
    {
        std::cout << "Creating a connection with ["
                  << socketAddr.host().toString()
                  << "] through port [" << socketAddr.port() << "] ...";
        try
        {
            // socket.connect(socketAddr);
            // std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
        }
        catch (Poco::Exception err)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Socket connection error: [" << err.displayText() << "]" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Send a message to the connected server
    bool sendMessage()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        const char channel[] = "fool";
        std::string channelPort = std::to_string(5577);

        try
        {
            std::string message;

            std::cout << "Enter a message to send to the server: ";
            std::cin >> message;

            json msg = json(json_object_arg, {{"$op", "create_channel"}, {"$svc", "zmq"}, {"channel_name", channel}, {"port", channelPort}});
            std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
            jsoncons::cbor::encode_cbor(msg, buffer);
            zmq::const_buffer msg_out = zmq::buffer(buffer);

            if (message.compare("exit") != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Sending the message to the server!\n\t";
                // socket.sendBytes(msg_out.data(), msg_out.size());
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Poco::Exception err)
        {
            std::cout << "Data send error: [" << err.displayText() << "]" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int port = 2001;
    std::string hostname = "10.0.12.97";

    // Handle the server-client connection and send some JSON
    try
    {
        ClientHandler handler(hostname, port);

        if (handler.connected())
            while (handler.sendMessage())
                ;
    }
    catch (Poco::Exception err)
    {

        std::cout << "Handler Error -> " << err.displayText() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, How do I get from this ^ to Websockets?

I have been reading and digging through the documentation for Poco Websockets. At first, I thought I needed to figure out the HTTPClientSession, HTTPRequest, and HTTPResponse objects I saw in so many examples. However, looking at Documentation for Poco Websockets constructors, it appeared all I needed to do was pass it a socket connection. So spent some time trying to figure that out, but after going back to the documentation it appears that it specifies that I need to send it a socket that is already a Websocket.

```
Creates a WebSocket from another Socket, which must be a WebSocket,
```

That's what I get for not actually reading it. So I spent some more time reading through the constructors and it appears that I do in fact have to send at least 3 arguments.

```
WebSocket
WebSocket(
    HTTPClientSession & cs,
    HTTPRequest & request,
    HTTPResponse & response
);

Creates a client-side WebSocket, using the given HTTPClientSession and HTTPRequest for the initial handshake (HTTP Upgrade request).
```

So I'm now back to HTTPClientSession, HTTPRequest, and HTTPResponse objects.

I think I understand HTTPClientSession. Here I should provide the Server name and port. So updating the code above should look something like this

```
...
Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession cs;

public:
    ClientHandler(std::string h, int p) : host(h), port(p), cs(h, p) 
...
```

HTTPResponse looks to be a pointer to a response object for the WebSocket to return the HTTPRequest response. Looks to contain a status code, date, reason(not sure what reason is)

The HTTPRequest is a point of interest. I'm lost as to what I need to format this as. There are three arguments for the request.

- Method - this looks like nothing more than telling the server that you are requesting something or looking to hand something over.

  - HTTP_POST - I would assume this is what I want?
  - HTTP_GET
- URI - for HTTP_GET this would be the path of the resource I'm looking to retrieve. And for Post, this would be the path that I would like to post something to on the server
- Version - looks to be self-explanatory, as this is the HTTP version I would like to use.

but here is the rub of it, I do not want to post/get anything that's associated with a URI, I'm just looking to transfer a JSON packet and manage it on the other end. I've found a [sample code of a client](https://gist.github.com/tuxmartin/1218851b7e025f68ecc50f949c9dd332) that uses this information, but I don't understand why it's using HTTP_GET, and the reason for the /?encode=text reference. I can't seem to find details anywhere on it. That leads me to the set value of the request object, don't understand what the "set()" call is for or how it would work in my situation.

With the new information, I updated my constructor to this.

```
...
Poco::Net::WebSocket *ws;

public:
    ClientHandler(std::string h, int p) : host(h), port(p)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
        
        // Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession cs(h, p);         
        Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession cs(host, port);
        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text", HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
        // req.set("origin", "http://www.websocket.org");
        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse resp;

        ws = new WebSocket(cs, req, resp);

        std::cout << "Host: " << host << "\tPort: " << port << std::endl;
    }
...
```

However, I enter the constructor but never leave it. It gets hung up when I attempt to create the WebSocket. I'm assuming it doesn't like something. I tried the HTTPClientSesseion cs two ways. and leaving the req.set() in as well. Just hangs.

Could someone lend me some insight as to how I can get Poco::Net::Websocket running? and some information so I can understand what's going on a bit better. So when I attempt the server-side I will have some more information that will help.

Comment: Like you said, I highly doubt using Websockets is going to lower your latency.  Typically UDP can give you lower latency since it is connectionless.  I think you need to benchmark your system to be sure you know where the problem exists.  Also, make sure latency truly is the bottleneck and not throughput.  Concurrent connections/threads can present major problems too.  Also maybe explore AF_XDP address family as long as your HW supports it for bypassing the network stack, if you need to.

Comment: @CookieButter between zmq and websocket, there was a massive decrease in latency, I ended up using Boost, instead of Poco. There was way more available documentation. If you look at this link, https://github.com/goldsborough/ipc-bench, benchmarking has been done to show a simple difference in different inter-process-communication throughput, and websockets do offer higher latency than sockets, in my case this would include websockets.

Answer (score 1):

I started using Poco today and needed to achieve a WebSocket client sending & receiving a JSON message. Here is a "bare-minimum" class wrapping the needed functionalities from Poco:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Buffer.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/WebSocket.h>

using namespace Poco::Net;

class PocoWebSocket
{
public:
    PocoWebSocket(std::string const & host, Poco::UInt16 port, std::string const & route)
        : _session(host, port)
        , _request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, route + "?encoding=text",
                   HTTPRequest::HTTP_1_1)
        , _socket(_session, _request, _response)
    {}
    ~PocoWebSocket() { _socket.shutdown(); }

public:
    void sendTextFrame  (std::string_view msg) { sendImpl(msg, WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);   }
    void sendBinaryFrame(std::string_view msg) { sendImpl(msg, WebSocket::FRAME_BINARY); }
    auto receiveTextFrame() -> std::string
    {
        int flags = 0;
        Poco::Buffer<char> buffer(0);
        auto const sz = _socket.receiveFrame(buffer, flags);
        return std::string(buffer.begin(), static_cast<std::size_t>(sz));
    }

private:
    void sendImpl(std::string_view msg, WebSocket::SendFlags flags)
    {
        _socket.sendFrame(msg.data(), msg.size(), flags);
    }

private:
    HTTPClientSession _session;
    HTTPRequest       _request;
    HTTPResponse      _response;
    WebSocket         _socket;
};

static int die(int exitCode, std::string const & msg)
{
    std::cerr << "[FATAL] " << msg << std::endl;
    return exitCode;
}

int main() try
{
    PocoWebSocket socket("localhost", HTTPSession::HTTP_PORT, "/");
    auto const msg = socket.receiveTextFrame();
    std::cout << "recv: " << msg << std::endl;
    // parse JSON here
}
catch (Poco::Exception const & e) { return die(e.code(), e.displayText()); }
catch (std::exception  const & e) { return die(EXIT_FAILURE, e.what());    }
```